# What is the syntax for using a token on webform confirmation page for Drupal 7 Webform 4

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

I have an Email field on my webform with the key email_address. On successful webform submission, I would like to display the confirmation message as.

Further instructions have been sent to xyz@yahoo.com [Email Address which is submitted on the webform]

I tried using

> [webform:val-email_address] 
>   [submission:values:email_adddress]

With no luck. The text format is Safe HTML. Not sure if this is causing that
This is on Drupal 7 - Webform version 4.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Webform tokens module](https://drupal.org/project/webform_tokens)

> Webform Tokens provides tokens for user form submissions for forms
>   created with the module Webform 3.

But Webform4 has this feature inbuilt, you might try this [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/modal_forms_webform_confirmation_token.patch) to fix it.

**OR**

You can try writing [webform-confirmation.tpl.php](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!templates!webform-confirmation.tpl.php/7) to achieve the same.

Comment: I am already using the Webform 4 version